# John Smith? Who is it?

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme

> They say "John Smith" is England's name most common
>
> When you get the answer, you're going to say "c'mon!"
>
> As you see it's almost all there at the start
>
> Just a little "mark up" and we can race up the chart
>
> To wit, this charming man is a sometime pretender
>
> But recognize for how well he jangles the fender

Who is it?

Clue spoiler:

> Irishpanda has most clues explained in the answer, except the "mark up" clue is more of a straight up word play.  Our mystery man's last name is a synonym of mark (a marked up item can be said to be "marred") and the title or start of the puzzle "John Smith", with text inserted (or "marked up" in *three* wordplay meanings) gives both his name and primary affiliation: John*ny Marr,* Smith.

Comment: Between "mark up" and "c'mon" I couldn't get Marky Mark out of my head

Comment: @computhomas, with *John Smith* and *Who*, I was thinking of the Doctor, especially with the current one playing guitar

Comment: @SeanC maybe if it was "Alonzi!" instead of "c'mon"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

He is

> Johnny Marr

They say "John Smith" is England's name most common

When you get the answer, you're going to say "c'mon!"

As you see it's almost all there at the start

> His name is John, and he was a member of The Smiths

Just a little "mark up" and we can race up the chart

> Another word for mark is mar, a play on Marr.

To wit, this charming man is a sometime pretender

> After the smiths, he played with the Pretenders. "Charming Man" is a Smiths' song.

But recognize for how well he jangles the fender

> His trademark sound can be called "jangly" and he was known to play a Fender guitars.

Comment: Damn this seems like it fits well. Good job, I couldn't get the mark up part

Comment: If he played the guitar, the fender is a guitar brand

Comment: Almost all there except the mark clue.  Spoiler added...

Comment: So my ORIGINAL guess was actually right.

Answer (score 1):

Is it:

> John Lennon

**Reasoning:**

They say "John Smith" is England's name most common

> Pretty close to John Lennon, who is English

When you get the answer, you're going to say "c'mon!"

> Reference to song [Please Please me](http://www.metrolyrics.com/please-please-me-lyrics-beatles.html)

As you see it's almost all there at the start

> John Lennon is close to John Smith

Just a little "mark up" and we can race up the chart

> Not sure

To wit, this charming man is a sometime pretender

> Also not sure

But recognize for how well he jangles the fender

> John Lennon was known for using a Fender Stratocaster as his guitar

Comment: Not who I'm looking for!

Comment: Am I on the right track? because I have a few other options in a similar vein

Comment: You got the fender

Answer (score 1):

Here's another go:

> [James Honeyman-Scott](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Honeyman-Scott)

**Reasoning:**

They say "John Smith" is England's name most common

> James is close to John and he is from England

When you get the answer, you're going to say "c'mon!"

> Could be a reference to [Middle of the Road](https://play.google.com/music/preview/Tje4lqddnzuzw7imjnerd5okwda?lyrics=1&utm_source=google&utm_medium=search&utm_campaign=lyrics&pcampaignid=kp-lyrics)

As you see it's almost all there at the start

> Same reasoning as the first line, first name is close to John, he is from England

Just a little "mark up" and we can race up the chart

> Not sure about this one

To wit, this charming man is a sometime pretender

> He is the lead guitarist for The Pretenders

But recognize for how well he jangles the fender

> He is very well known for his guitar playing. His wife is also named Peggy Sue Fender